# where to store encrypted files in android

Tags: android, audio

In my application, the media player should decrypt the audio file which is protected with a passphrase for temporarly usage. After playing the audio file, the decrypted file must be deleted permenantly. Btw, I store the encrypted data under assets folder.
The question is, where to should I put the decrypted file? It must be the place, which user can not access to.

Answer (score 0):

For a rooted phone this is impossible, for non rooted phones any place under the /data/data/namepsace/* directories are somewhat difficult to get at due to file permissions.